# How to access pod from outside world

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I am creating two pods one Golang app and another PostgreSQL on K3s. Both pods are running, but when I try to access my Golang application using the following URL through Postman, it gives me a time-out error.

```
URL : http://public_ip:loadbalancer_port/

e.g: http://1.2.3.4:31265/getusers
```

When I try to access the same URL with the curl command from the same server, then it gives me  proper response.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue?

I trying to access my golang application from outside which is in k3s pod.

Comment: make sure that you're `LoadBalancer` type service is actually pointing to your Pods by verifying the selector labels, target port etc